# What APIs of the .NETStandard are actually implemented in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard

How can I find out if an .NETStandard API is actually implemented/supported by Xamarin.Android? I have a WCF net.tcp client implemented in a .NETStandard1.4 library. I reference this library from a Xamarin.Android app and try to call a client method.
It compiles fine, but throws a `NotImplementedException` on the client method call.

So can it be, that Xamarin.Android doesn't implement some APIs but still "supports" .NETStandard1.4? Im asking because Im not able to find anything saying that it is not supported, all the classes/methods I want to use are documented in Xamarins online docu (e.g. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ServiceModel.ClientBase%3CTChannel%3E/) and no mention of "Not Implemented", but I get the `NotImplementedException`. At the moment I can't tell if it is really not supported or if there is something messed up with my installation/project.

If yes, what exactly is the purpose of the .NETStandard libraries, if anyone simply can claim to support it and throw `NotImplementedException` on everthing?

For completeness:

Xamarin.Android app:

```
// MainActivity.cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://192.168.192.189:8550/iQOSApp_AppService");
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            var client = new iQOSApp.Clients.AppContractClient(binding, endpoint);
            int n = client.GetData(0); // NotImplementedException
        }
    }
}
```

.NETStandard Library:

```
// Clients.cs
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace iQOSApp.Clients
{


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "iQOSApp.Clients.IAppContract")]
    public interface IAppContract
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IAppContract/GetData", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IAppContract/GetDataResponse")]
        int GetData(int value);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IAppContract/GetData", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IAppContract/GetDataResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> GetDataAsync(int value);
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface IAppContractChannel : iQOSApp.Clients.IAppContract, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class AppContractClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<iQOSApp.Clients.IAppContract>, iQOSApp.Clients.IAppContract
    {

        public AppContractClient()
        {
        }

        public AppContractClient(string endpointConfigurationName) :
                base(endpointConfigurationName)
        {
        }

        public AppContractClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public AppContractClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public AppContractClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public int GetData(int value)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetData(value);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> GetDataAsync(int value)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetDataAsync(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using VS 2017 RC

Comment: You might try to upgrade to the latest Cycle 9 release (just available today) to see if this issue has been fixed, but generally speaking .NET Standard support on Xamarin platforms are not yet that reliable. It might fully work only when .NET Core 2.0 is available.

Comment: Can you say anything as to how likely it is that Xamarin will fully support it once .NET Core 2.0 is available?

Comment: if you do check Mono repo at GitHub, you will see the holes are being filled for .NET Standard 2.0 compatibility. The current Xamarin.Android/Mono 4.8 is just 1.6 compliant, while you still see such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So can it be, that Xamarin.Android doesn't implement some APIs but still "supports" .NETStandard1.4?

Yes that is correct. In fact there are many old platforms that will throw NIE(Not Implemented Exceptions) in areas that they do not have implementations of. This is more of a Mono compatibility thing: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

You could implement your own platform and throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` all over your implementations and it would be considered "Supporting `netstandard`". Aaron Nurse has a good insight on this here: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7#gistcomment-1759645

Thus you are most likely running into an issue of Mono's WCF stack lacking certain functionality:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/

> In general, the Xamarin platform supports the same client-side subset of WCF that ships with the Silverlight runtime. This includes the most common encoding and protocol implementations of WCF — text-encoded SOAP messages over the HTTP transport protocol using the BasicHttpBinding class. In addition, WCF support requires the use of tools only available in a Windows environment to generate the proxy.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/wcf/

**Note:** Be careful about the Xamarin documentation for some of these types. They are pulled directly from MSDN and do not mean that everything is supported if it's listed in the BCL. For a more accurate assembly list, please see:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/

You are better off looking at the Silverlight MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: The first paragraph is probably wrong. Many platforms should throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` as stated [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md), not `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: @LexLi Yes you are right. I'm merely trying to explain the concept WRT mono: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ I'll edit to make more sense.

Comment: I tried using SlSvcUtil.exe to generate Silverlight compatible clients, but the exact same exception was thrown. Anyway, you answered my question, thank you.